# Не запоминается значение в localStorage

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Код предназначен для выбора `css` файла для сайта.
Почему не запоминается выбор стиля и нет возможности применить стиль повторно, т.е если нажал на `<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme1')"></li>` а потом на `<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme2')"></li>` то первый уже не нажимается.

кнопки

```
<ul class="colors">
<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme1')"></li>                    
<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme2')"></li>
<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme3')"></li>
<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme4')"></li>
<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme5')"></li>
<li onclick="setCssTheme('theme6')"></li>
</ul>
```

js

```
// Сохранение темы в localStorage
const saveCssTheme = function (themes) {
localStorage.cssTheme = themes;
}

// Получение темы из localStorage, либо дефолтной
const getCssTheme = function () {
return localStorage.cssTheme || 'theme1';
}

// Загрузка css файла
const loadCssTheme = function (themes) {
const link = document.createElement('link');
link.id = themes;
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = 'stylesheet';
link.href = `/css/${themes}.css`;

// если мы уже загрузили стили, то не нужно делать это еще раз
if(document.getElementById(themes)) return;

document.head.appendChild(link);
}

// Установка темы
const setCssTheme = function(themes) {
loadCssTheme(themes);
saveCssTheme(themes);
document.body.setAttribute('class', themes);
}

// Использование при загрузке страницы
document.addEventListener("load", function () {
const themes = getCssTheme();

setCssTheme(themes);
});
```

Comment: В отладчика не пробовали смотреть?

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что _первый уже не нажимается_? добавь [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть проблему.

Comment: Не нажимается, потому-что стиль не меняется, который уже был ранее включен.

Comment: Что в консоли? Ошибки? Если есть, то какие?

Comment: А в смысле не нажимается? Ты тему уже зааппендил, она так и болтается у тебя в хеде. С локалстораджем, уверен, что все в порядке.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос ссылку с примером

Comment: @steep. И посещаемость сайта возросла :D

Comment: А почему думаешь я в вопрос ссылку поставил? Потому-что оттуда её можно удалить.

Comment: Где ещё пример такой сделать не знаю, кучу стилей нужно писать.

Comment: @Grundy по твоей просьбе добавил пример, теперь можно запустить и увидеть проблему.

Comment: `// если мы уже загрузили стили, то не нужно делать это еще раз
if(document.getElementById(themes)) return;` - ты сам не добавляешь стили. поэтому ничего и не происходит. но вообще темы делаются не совсем так: просто цвета все выстраиваются с соответствии с самым внешним классом и по кнопке просто этот класс меняешь

Comment: Удалил эту строку, теперь нормально, а что с сохранением в локалстораж? Обновляешь страницу стили сбрасываются, почему?

Comment: @Grundy Есть лучший вариант по этой теме?

Comment: @steep, скорее всего в document нет события `load`

Comment: Как его прописать?

Comment: @steep, можно вообще без событий, это же стили - их все равно когда добавлять